# Does the following commutative diagram follow from the fact that a braiding is a natural transformation?

Tags: category-theory

A [braided monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braided_monoidal_category) is a monoidal category with a braiding (a commutativity constraint $\gamma_{A,B}: A \otimes B \to B \otimes A$) which satisfies the hexagon identities:
$$
\gamma_{A, B \otimes C} = (1 \otimes \gamma_{A,C})(\gamma_{A,B} \otimes 1) \quad (1) \\
\gamma_{A \otimes B, C} = (\gamma_{A,C} \otimes 1) (1 \otimes \gamma_{B,C}). \quad (2)
$$
In a monoidal category, we have two functors $F,G: \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$, $F(A, B) = A \otimes B$,  $G(A,B) = B \otimes A$. The braiding $\gamma_{A,B}: A \otimes B \to B \otimes A$ is a natural transformation: $\gamma: F \to G$.

Does the following commutative diagram follow from the fact that a braiding is a natural transformation?

$$\begin{array}
{cccc} A \otimes B \otimes C  & \stackrel{\gamma_{A, B \otimes C}}{\longrightarrow} & B \otimes C \otimes A \\
\downarrow{\gamma_{B,C}} & & \downarrow{\gamma_{B,C}} \\
A \otimes C \otimes B & \stackrel{\gamma_{A, C \otimes B}}{\longrightarrow} & C \otimes B \otimes A  
\end{array}
$$
I tried to use the definition of natural transformation. Which morphism $f: \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$ should we take? If we take $f=(1, \gamma_{B,C}): (A, B \otimes C) \to (A, C \otimes B)$, then we have $F(f): A \otimes B \otimes C \to B \otimes C \otimes A$ given by $F(f)=1 \otimes \gamma_{B \otimes C}$, where $F$ is defined above. Similarly, we have $G(f): B \otimes C \otimes A \to C \otimes B \otimes A$ given by $G(f)= \gamma_{B \otimes C} \otimes 1$, where $G$ is defined above. Therefore we have the above commutative diagram. Is this correct?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is because in your diagram the vertical arrows are in fact from left to right $A\otimes\gamma_{B,C}$ and $\gamma_{B,C}\otimes A$ and that the horizontal lines are the corresponding natural transformations, $\gamma_{A,-} : A\otimes- \to -\otimes A$.

More precisely, let $F:[M\mapsto A \otimes M, f\mapsto id_A \otimes f]$ and  $G:[M \mapsto M\otimes A,f\mapsto f \otimes id_A]$ then $\gamma_{A,-}$ is by definition a natural transformation from $F$ to $G$ and the diagram commutes indeed.